# How to process old excel .xls files using POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxl

I switched from jxl to poi since POI has more features. However, I wasn't able to process the xls files that were generated in the old format. Now I am getting this error:

> org.apache.poi.hssf.OldExcelFormatException: The supplied spreadsheet
>   seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8
>   format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)

Now I am thinking to use both JXL as wells as POI depending on the xls version so for old format xls files I will use jxl while for newer versions I will use POI. Is this a good solution? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Is that, in fact, an Excel 5.0/7.0 file?

Comment: Yes I validated that it is an Excel 5/7 file (Office 95)

Comment: Using single API is definitely better as it would have reduced the complexity a lot. But only these two are the most mature API to read Excel. So as per my opinion its is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For old Excel format files, you have the following alternatives:

1. [HSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/), the `POI` implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format.

   - If you just want to extract the textual content, then  you can use [OldExcelExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/OldExcelExtractor.html) which will pull only the 
     text and numbers from the file.
   - If you need the values from a specific cells, then you'll need to take an 
     approach a bit like `OldExcelExtractor`, process the file at the record 
     level, and check for the co-ordinates on [OldStringRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/OldStringRecord.html), [NumberRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/NumberRecord.html), [OldFormulaRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/OldFormulaRecord.html) and friends.
2. Like you already mentioned, [JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) can handle some cases too.
3. Use a [JDBC/ODBC](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/UseJDBCODBCbridgetoreadfromExcel.htm) driver. It is not as flexible as `HSSF` but for some old formats it is the only way to extract the information.

Comment: The link referenced by the text "JDBC/ODBC" does not appear to point to any relevant content.

Comment: @James Thanks, I updated the link to a new url, it seems that the previous page was removed :(

Comment: Hi Thanks your answers, just I would know if there is a way to detect the format of Excel file is BIFF5?

Comment: @esprittn You can check the `BOF` (Beginning of File) record.  See page 43 from here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat%28xls%29Specification.pdf for more details.

Answer (score -5):

as per my knowledge you can use this code to read excel files of the .xls format

```
FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(new File("filename.xls"));
Wookbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(in);
```

to read the new excel versions(2007 and up):

```
 FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(new File("filename.xls"));
    Wookbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(in);
```

external jar files that you will need:

```
 1. poi-3.9 
 2. dom4j-1.6.1
 3. XMLbeams-2.5.0
```

if you're work only requires you to work with .xls then only poi-3.0 will suffice. You need the other jars to work witht the new versions of excel.

Comment: I think you are referring to issues going from the old binary .xls format to newer XML based .xlsx formats but I think the question is referring to very old .xls binary formats that POI can't read - it can read newer .xls files - nothing to do with being binary or XML based format - just the older .xls files seem to not be supported by POI.