# Accessing cells of an old excel .xls file with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to parse old .xls Excel file, with only one sheet inside. There are no formulas and if it is no much different than it would be if I were using .csv. I just want the values that are there. How can I access the value inside of a certain cell?

First I tried using POI, I wrote my code to discover the error message:

> org.apache.poi.hssf.OldExcelFormatException: The supplied spreadsheet seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8 format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)

I have read the question [How to process old excel .xls files using POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336457/how-to-process-old-excel-xls-files-using-poi) and I couldn't understand (after reading the documentation) how I read the value on a certain cell.

This was the best I could do:

```java
private static String extractExcel(File fileEntry) {
    OldExcelExtractor wb = new OldExcelExtractor(fileEntry);
    return wb.getText();
}
```

I had two problems here:

1. It returns a string, a cell by line.
2. It converts integers to float.

Comment: Read the source code for the old extractor, then implement your own logic similar to that?

Comment: Is this the best I can do? Because Python Pandas can read these files.

Comment: Use Pandas then? Apache POI has low-level record support, it's not too much work to use, the old excel extractor is a great guide to what's needed. Being open source, you can quickly see what's needed for your own logic!